# How do you find rO when solving this differential amplifier?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, differential

[image]

gm could be determined using Jacoletto (40*Ic, where Ic was found while solving the bias point)?
[image]
Some of my attempts at solving the circuit

Comment: you should show some of your own work, even if you think it is wrong. People will be more willing to guide you.

Comment: @Juan thanks for the advice, I just did.

Comment: Do you know VA of the transistors? you can determine ro from that.